# How to configure reverse lookup for a /29 net?

Tags: domain-name-system, solaris, bind

I have a /29 net for which I want a bind instance to be responsible for doing the reverse lookup. I know that for a net like 192.168.1.0/24 I could configure my zone as in

`zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" in {
...
}`

But now I only want to manage the 192.168.1.64/29 net from this DNS server. Anything I have to set in the server responsible for the neighbors?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/22743/reverse-dns-in-a-cidr-world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the DNS server that is authoritative for the enclosing /24, setup a series of CNAMEs to an appropriate namespace you setup on your server, as per RFC2317.