# Setting up PTR in Plesk

Tags: iis-7, email

I added the following entry (Plesk -> Domain settings -> DNS Settings):

12.345.678.912 / 24 PTR mail.domain.com

The IP address matches the mail.domain.com IP address as that is the one which sends out emails.

I checked the PTR [here](http://www.ptrrecord.net/ptr-record-ip.php) and the checker says that there is no PTR record. I tried with mail.domain.com

How to setup the PTR records correctly from Plesk? Any clues how to settle this down?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know anything about plesk, what why did you give this `/24` netmask for the IN PTR RR? This doesn't look right to me.

Comment: Thanks for the comment; I was following up instructions from [here](http://support.sherweb.com/Faqs/Show/how-to-add-modify-or-delete-resources-records-plesk). In one of the screenshots they had /24 so I did the same. What should I enter instead?

Comment: Ah, OK, thanks for the link. It looks correct. I think Plesk needs this to find the correct ptr-zone. Anyway, looks correct to me. Sorry, can't help any further.

Answer (score 4):

Who hosts your plesk server?

Usually your hosting provider who gave you the IP address will run reverse DNS for their IP addresses and will need to add the reverse entry to their system. You do not add PTR records to the zone file for your domain.

It's possible you have been given a range and they have delegated control of this range to your own DNS servers, but probably not. Either way the admins who assigned you the IP should be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a dedicated server coming with preinstalled Plesk. I called server tech support and they said that this should be done through Plesk and that there is nothing to be done on their side. I do not know so much about the server admin or domain stuff - can you please suggest what should I do? Is there something I should ask them again?

Comment: @Ivanhoe123 Unless your ISP has (a) given you a full /24 (class C block) of address space, or (b) [delegated the reverse range to a zone/server you control](http://serverfault.com/questions/22743/reverse-dns-in-a-cidr-world) **your ISP** must make the reverse `PTR` entries on the server that is authoritative for the reverse zone in question. (We could tell you more if you would give us the actual IP addresses in question.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply - I just called them and it seems that they should have done something on their end. They added the PTR and said that it should be propagated within the next few hours. Will keep you posted.

Comment: @voretaq7 seems it's working properly now :) I checked it with some email providers (AOL for example) that I know that require PTR to be setup and emails are received without any problems. Thanks a lot for your help :) please move (repost?) your comment as an answer so I can accept it as a solution and award the bounty.

Comment: I'll award the bounty to USD Matt as this was the only answer to the question.